# Color will be black when cycle redering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

material color is not not reflected when cycle redering
I change material color, but color is black when cycle redering.
when eevee, nothing problem.
[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6819" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6819/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

You need to disable autosmooth normals in Object Data.

*Properties->Normals->Auto Smooth uncheck*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!
I can change the color.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can now mark my answer as accepted :).