# Procedual material not applying correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, node-editor, shaders

i have an issue i need to fix ASAP because is getting in the way of my work, i started modelling with Blender and i love it, specially Vehicle modeling, and i have an issue, i created procedual materials like Metal, glass, tinted glass, carbon fiber using nodes in blender without any textures, and the problem i have is that whe ni apply the material in the vehicle for expample the windows i'm not getting the result i should be getting but when i apply the material to a plane or monkey head it applyes correctly, i have a few Screenshots to show you guys what i'm talking about with hope you guys can hellp me understand what's the problem cuz i really can't find any solution to this...

[image]

[image]

here another example on my carbon fiber material that's different in both meshes but is the same exact material... i really need help with this. i may be a noob and this is an easy thing to solve but i really need help to figure it out...

**PS:** english is not my native lenguage and in the picture i wrote in spanish in red "mismo material" it means "same material"
**PS2**: i'm rendering with experimental build GPU supported (Cycles)

Comment: Is there anything different about the texture coordinate mapped to the different sections?

Comment: Hello :). Consider sharing the file or part of it, so others can take a look.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Window color is black when cycle redering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158031/78972)

Comment: so you have this purple thing instead of a transparent glass, correct ? could be a UV mapping problem ? or you need to recompute normal ?

Comment: also, please consider using a title that describe your problem so it can be searched on google and help other peoples with the same problem :)

Comment: is not purple is blue and the carbon fiber has the same problem as the glass, i not using any UV's it's all procedual but why does it work win a plane and not in my model.

How can i share the .Blend file if that helps

Comment: @JachymMichal also the auto smooth is turned off, just checked

Comment: To share your file use GDrive/Dropbox or our local [Blend-exchange site](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if the file is small enough :).

Comment: on it....wait a sec

Comment: @JachymMichal check if ur able to download the file

https://www.dropbox.com/home/LamborghiniModel?preview=lamborghiniaventador9.blend

Comment: also here just in case is a problem with dropbox

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hMiLheRcF-1EPrItxQEED0qpgHoMq0d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello :). I checked the file, you need to recalculate normals for the material to work properly.

Comment: @JachymMichal it did! all this time i was recalculating the insides! not the outside normals, thanks a lot!